# how to display json data in the Table flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I want to display all the json data from the database into the table, but I am confused that the solution from json is plain text. I don't really understand about using Map , because this makes my code error

```
            FutureBuilder(
                future: UserController.getActivity(_selectedUser),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    var item = snapshot.data;
                    Map<String, dynamic> activity = item[snapshot]['activity'];
                    //print(snapshot.data.toString());
                    print(activity);
                    return Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Table(
                          defaultColumnWidth: FixedColumnWidth(150.0),
                          border: TableBorder(
                            horizontalInside: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              style: BorderStyle.solid,
                              width: 1.0,
                            ),
                            verticalInside: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              style: BorderStyle.solid,
                              width: 1.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          children: [
                            TableRow(children: [
                              TableCell(
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                     new Text(snapshot.data["project"]),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            ])
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                      child: Text("No data displayed"),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
```

when I try to use this code that appears error *_FutureBuilderState  # 71363):
Expected a value of type 'int', but has one of type 'AsyncSnapshot '*

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line:

```
Map<String, dynamic> activity = item[snapshot]['activity'];
```

You are trying to use an AsyncSnapshot as a key of the object. You have to use only numbers for positions or literal keys, depending on the structure of the Json that you have as a response.

Comment: Yes, all the data that you have as a response is in item.